# Express post all routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on an express project and I have a search bar in the navigation bar for the layout page (I am using jade). Every page will extend to the layout, and this means it will have the search bar on every page. Currently, this is my code:

```
app.post('thing', (res, req) => {
  console.log('form: ' + req.body);
}

app.post('/*', (res, req) => {
  console.log("search: " + req.body);
}
```

How do I make it so that the second post calls on every page, including the /thing/, as well as the first post only calling on /thing/. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it by changing the second post handler to a [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html):

```
app.post((res, req, next) => {
  console.log("search: " + req.body);
  next();
}

app.post('thing', (res, req) => {
  console.log('form: ' + req.body);
}
```